# Is there a term for a word that is the same upside-down?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I know *palindrome* is the term for a word that works backwards and forwards, but is there a similar term for a word that can be flipped/reversed and remain the same?

For example, the word *SWIMS* or the number *6009*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with English Language or Usage. This is about glyph shapes in typography. Next, model trains?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why is this closed as offtopic? Asking for the English word for a concepts is 90% of the questions I see here. Every one of the related topics I see is "Word for ___" or "Is there a term for ___"

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. If the request were for a list of words, perhaps a puzzle site or meta would be appropriate. It's clearly asking for a term of art.

Comment: @trlkly - we've reopened it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The examples, *SWIMS* and *6009*, aren't the same upside down, so I assume you mean under a 180 rotation. I've always heard them referred to as [rotational ambigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram).

Comment: A [Strobogrammatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobogrammatic_number) is rotationally symmetric